# IOS - How expensive is reloadData?

Tags: ios, performance, tableview, reloaddata

I as wondering how expensive reloadData on tableView is. I wanted to refresh the tableview every 5 seconds. Is that going to cause any performance issues?

Comment: whoever downvoted this question earlier, I honestly feel this is not a bad question. (at least tell the noob why such a question should not be posted instead of just downvoting)

Comment: The only real answer is for you to use Instruments and measure your code.  Your code will operate differently than anyone else's.  Do what seems best, then measure.  Then change according to any poor performance characteristics.  Yes, it's the same I answer I give to everyone asking performance related questions -- because it's the only real answer until you actually have hard performance numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Reload data will call the two main methods on your table view data source, `numberOfRowsInSection` and then iterate over `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` for the visible cells required, depending on your tableView's `contentOffset`

If your app scrolls nicely already then the only performance hit your app will endure is if you're doing a lot of work in `numberOfRowsInSection` (like hitting the network or something time consuming).

**Edit:** As noted, `heightForRow:atIndexPath:` can also be a pain point if you're using it to do complex calculations for different height cells.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for answering the question. My heights of the rows are constant and there are no complex calculations within the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jessedc answer,

If all your rows are of same height, then `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is more expensive than `tableview.rowHeight`.

If you have a lot of rows with varying heights for each row, and you are calculating the height of the row each time the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is called, then its even more expensive.

There are a lot of factors involved in deciding how expensive the `reloadData` call is. Everything depends on what and how much you are doing each time the delegate methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

If applicable to your situation, an NSFetchedResultsController can notify your table view when the data changes, instead of refreshing it every "n" seconds.